# Headers of HTTP request have no Origin

Tags: express, nginx, cors, http-headers, cross-domain

Why do HTTP request headers have no Origin?
I'm facing a CORS conflict after any request from my frontend to my backend.

I have two projects. Both located at one server and with one public IP but different domains.

###### Project #1:

**Frontend** (React.js)
IP - 84.201.143.32
Domain - https://place.nomoredomains.xyz
**Backend** (Node.js, express, mongoDB)
IP - 84.201.143.32
Domain - https://api.place.nomoredomains.xyz

###### Project #2:

**Frontend** (React.js)
IP - 84.201.143.32
Domain - https://ypdiploma.nomoreparties.co/
**Backend** (Node.js, express, mongoDB)
IP - 84.201.143.32
Domain - https://api.ypdiploma.nomoreparties.co

Both projects works through Nginx.
Here is sites-available/default config:

```
server {

      server_name api.place.nomoredomains.xyz;

   location / {
                proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
      }

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/place.nomoredomains.xyz/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/place.nomoredomains.xyz/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}

server {

      server_name place.nomoredomains.xyz;

      root /home/lexev/react-mesto-api-full-gha/frontend/build;

      location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
      }

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
     ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/place.nomoredomains.xyz/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/place.nomoredomains.xyz/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}


server {

      server_name api.ypdiploma.nomoreparties.co;

      location / {
                proxy_pass http://localhost:3001;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
      }

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/place.nomoredomains.xyz/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/place.nomoredomains.xyz/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}

server {

      server_name ypdiploma.nomoreparties.co;

      root /home/lexev/ypdiploma/movies-explorer-frontend/build;

      location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
      }

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/place.nomoredomains.xyz/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/place.nomoredomains.xyz/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}


server {
    if ($host = place.nomoredomains.xyz) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


      listen 80;

      server_name place.nomoredomains.xyz;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot


}server {
    if ($host = api.place.nomoredomains.xyz) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


      listen 80;

      server_name api.place.nomoredomains.xyz;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot


}

server {
    if ($host = ypdiploma.nomoreparties.co) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


      listen 80;

      server_name ypdiploma.nomoreparties.co;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot


}


server {
    if ($host = api.ypdiploma.nomoreparties.co) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


      listen 80;

      server_name api.ypdiploma.nomoreparties.co;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot


}
```

Project #1 works properly and sending all request with Origin Header, but Project #2 do not send any Origin Header. Due to this i getting CORS conflict for Project #2.

Project #1 HTTP request: [Network Tab from Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nq6w8.png)

Project #2 HTTP request: [Network Tab from Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GXl6W.png)

CORS Error:
[image: screenshot]

I think you also may require corsHandler middleware code:

```js
const allowedCors = [
  'https://ypdiploma.nomoreparties.co',
  'http://ypdiploma.nomoreparties.co',
  'https://ypdiploma.nomoreparties.co/',
  'http://ypdiploma.nomoreparties.co/',
  'http://localhost:3000',
];

const corsHandler = (req, res, next) => {
  const { origin } = req.headers;
  const { method } = req;

  const DEFAULT_ALLOWED_METHODS = 'GET,HEAD,PUT,PATCH,POST,DELETE';
  const requestHeaders = req.headers['access-control-request-headers'];

  if (allowedCors.includes(origin)) {
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', origin);
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
  }

  if (method === 'OPTIONS') {
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', DEFAULT_ALLOWED_METHODS);
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', requestHeaders);
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
    return res.end();
  }

  return next();
};

module.exports = { corsHandler };
```

This is my app:

```js
require('dotenv').config();
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
const { errors } = require('celebrate');
const helmet = require('helmet');
const { requestLogger, errorLogger } = require('./middlewares/logger');
const { corsHandler } = require('./middlewares/cors');
const { limiter } = require('./middlewares/limiter');

const errorHandler = require('./middlewares/errorHandler');
const { MONGOOSE_DB } = require('./constants/constants');

const { PORT = 3001 } = process.env;

const app = express();
mongoose.connect(MONGOOSE_DB);

app.use(helmet());
app.use(corsHandler);
app.use(express.json());
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(requestLogger);

app.use('/', limiter, require('./routes/index'));

app.use(errorLogger);

app.use(errors());
app.use(errorHandler);

app.listen(PORT);
```

And finally fetch from Frontend part:

```js
class MainApi {
  constructor() {
    this._baseUrl = 'https://api.ypdiploma.nomoreparties.co'
    this._headers = {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    };
  }

  _getResponseData(res) {
    if (res.ok) {
      return res.json();
    } else {
      return Promise.reject(res);
    }
  }

  getUserinfo() {
    return fetch(this._baseUrl + '/users/me', {
      headers: this._headers,
      credentials: 'include',
    }).then((res) => this._getResponseData(res));
  }
}

const mainApi = new MainApi();

export default mainApi;
```

I tried to implement a CORS check with the Referer header, but it didn't works. I suspect that the problem is somewhere in NGINX's default config, but unfortunately I can't find where...

Comment: If you're facing a CORS error, always include the error message in your question. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Sorry for lack of info.
error added to question

Answer (score 1):

How mentioned @jub0bs, the rason was in handmade corsHandler. 
After using [Express's CORS middleware](https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cors.html) with correct settings everything is work!

Сonfigured cors middleware:

```
const cors = require('cors');

const corsHandler = cors({
  origin: [
    'https://ypdiploma.nomoreparties.co',
    'http://ypdiploma.nomoreparties.co',
    'http://localhost:3000',
  ],
  optionsSuccessStatus: 200,
  credentials: true,
});

module.exports = { corsHandler };
```

app:

```
require('dotenv').config();
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
const { errors } = require('celebrate');
const helmet = require('helmet');
const { corsHandler } = require('./middlewares/cors');
const { requestLogger, errorLogger } = require('./middlewares/logger');
const { limiter } = require('./middlewares/limiter');

const errorHandler = require('./middlewares/errorHandler');
const { MONGOOSE_DB } = require('./constants/constants');

const { PORT = 3001 } = process.env;

const app = express();
mongoose.connect(MONGOOSE_DB);

app.use(corsHandler);
app.use(helmet());
app.use(express.json());
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(requestLogger);

app.use('/', limiter, require('./routes/index'));

app.use(errorLogger);

app.use(errors());
app.use(errorHandler);

app.listen(PORT);
```